# How to test which MS Word files can be correctly edited in Google Docs?

Tags: microsoft-word, google-docs

Is there a way to test/verify which MS Word files can be correctly edited in Google Docs and no formatting will be lost if files are exported back to MS Word format?

Basically, I have quite a number of documents and I would like to verify if I can just move to Google Docs for editing and that import/edit/export will not break formatting.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what sort of formatting you're worried about getting broken?  I don't do this sort of thing extensively but I've never had any trouble myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are uploading the files and plans to edit, then the only option google have is to convert those files into Google Docs format.

Unfortunately, this conversion isn't always perfect. Depending on the level of formatting used in the original document, the converted Google Doc could turn out looking quite different. And  this changes may also include loss of information with loss of formatting.

Remember that you always have the option to store your files in their original file format if you'd prefer not to edit files online.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the formatting exactly, generally text and text effects (bold, underline...)should transfer.  Essentially anything that isn't graphical should work fine.

To be safe, always try to save in a .rtf format (when saving, click the arrow under the "save as" file name bar).